# Facebook iOS App Login fails with "Session Expired" when user is not logged into the Facebook App

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login

I have an iOS app that uses Facebook iOS Swift SDK for login. The flow is:

1. User clicks the login button on the app
2. User is redirected to the Facebook App
3. User logs in to the app
4. User is redirected back to the app when the login is successful

The above works fine when the user is already signed in to the Facebook App. However, if the user is not signed in the Facebook app and sign's in as step 3 of this workflow, the login fails with "Session Expired", "File Can't Be Opened" "This file type is unsupported"

[image: screenshot]

Has anyone seen this error before? What could be causing this?

Tried this on multiple devices with the same issue. It does work on the first install but then the state somehow gets messed up and I get the same error on subsequent logins.

Code for integration with Facebook is as follows:

- App Delegate application did finish launching with options call to SDK App Delegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}
```

- Open URL call to SDK App Delegate

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    }
```

- Facebook Login Button

```
        self.loginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [.userFriends, .email, .publicProfile])
        self.loginButton!.delegate = AppLoginButtonDelegate() // App's Login Button Delegate
        self.loginStackView!.addSubview(self.loginButton!)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue in our project.

Updating the Facebook App on our device resolved the issue.

Comment: You can't expect everyone to have their facebook apps up-to-date.

Comment: I updated the facebook app on the device and tried - The issue still exists :(